# How to have only one selected row across all details grid in a master detail KendoUI grid?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, grid, master-detail

I have a KendoUI grid displaying a list of customers (the master part). Each customer could have a list of users (the detail part)

Html page:

```
<kendo-grid options="mainGridOptions" k-on-change="onSelectedCustomerChanged({selected:data})">
<div k-detail-template>
    <div>
        <div kendo-grid k-options="detailGridOptions(dataItem)" k-on-change="onSelectedUserChanged({selected:data})"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js file:

```
$scope.mainGridOptions = {
  toolbar: ["excel"],
  columns: [{ field: "Fullname"}, { field: "Country.CountryName"}],
  selectable: "row",
  dataSource: {
      transport: {
          read: function (e) {
              $http.post("Services/Customer.svc/GetCustomers").
                  success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                      e.success(data.d);
                  }).
                  error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                      alert('something went wrong');
                      console.log(status);
                    });
            }
        }
    }
};
$scope.detailGridOptions = function (dataItem) {
    return {
        selectable: "row",
        dataSource: dataItem.Users,                       
        columns: [{ field: "UserName" },{ field: "Email" },{ field: "FullName" }]
    };
};
```

my data looks like :

```
customer 1  France
  user1   user1@domain.tld  user 1
  user2   user2@domain.tld  user 2
  user3   user3@domain.tld  user 3
customer 2  U.K.
  user4   user4@domain.tld  user 4
  user5   user5@domain.tld  user 5
```

I can click on customer row and user row.

when I click on user 4 the full row is selected.
If I click on user 2, the user 2's row is selected but the user 4's row remains selected. 
I would like to have only 1 user selected at a time.

I don't know if it is possible (and how to do that).
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Is that a typo where you have options instead of k-options on the first grid? Otherwise looks OK to me : http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-selectable

Comment: you're right.It was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In detailGridOptions add:

```
change: $scope.onDetailChange
```

And method:

```
$scope.onDetailChange = function (arg) {
    var grid = arg.sender;

    if ($scope.selectedStageRow != null && $scope.selectedStageRow.attr("data-uid") !== this.select().attr("data-uid")) {
        $scope.selectedStageRow.removeClass("k-state-selected");
    }
    var selected = this.select();
    $scope.selectedStageRow = selected;
    $scope.selectedItem = grid.dataItem(selected);      
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the change event to detect when a row is selected:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-change

then within the change event, if a row is selected, find all other detail grids and use the clearSelection() method to deselect any currently selected rows:

```
change: function(e) {
  if (this.select().length == 0) return;

  var curGrid = this.element;
  $("#grid .k-detail-cell .k-grid").each(function(idx, elem){
      if ($(elem)[0] != curGrid[0]){
       //clear previous selection 
        $(elem).data('kendoGrid').clearSelection()
      }
  });                          
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/udEVe)**

Comment: thank you, it works. I just had to remove the 'k-on-change' part on the html page, because it masked the change function you provide me.